# My code doesn't allow 2 times a character (how to fix)

Tags: python, replit

I need to write a code that counts the amount of closed area's en the amount of ends within a word (so B has 2 closed area's) but when 1 character sits 2 times within 1 question it only counts 1 time.

I tried something that should count the amount of characters but that just gived me more errorzs

```
G = 0
Chosen_word = str(input("Choose a word of max 60 character(only uppercase)"))
if "A" in Chosen_word:
  U = U + 2
  G = G + 1
```

if you type AA it should print 4 ends en 2 closed area's but it prints 2 ends en 1 closed area

Comment: I am struggling to follow your question. Please provide some example inputs and outputs so we can see the pattern. Is "en" for "and"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that downvotes don't mean that what you're tying to solve isn't a good problem; we use them to signify that your question should be edited to be more clear. I personally am confused because I don't know what the initial value of `U` is.

Answer (score 1):

You're only going through this code once - for the first letter. To go through *each letter*, you need to use a loop (a `for` loop that goes through every character would be best here):

```
for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter == 'A':
        U = U + 2
        G = G + 1
    elif letter == 'B':
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, gonna edit it now for the whole code

Comment: If you don't want to go through the effort of writing *that many* `if`/`elif` branches, one technique you could use is to make a dictionary up-front: `dct = {'A': {'U': 2. 'G': 1}, 'B': ...} and then, within the `for` loop, retrieve from dictionary instead of using conditionals (e.g. `U += dct[letter]['U']; G += dct[letter]['G']`)

Answer (score 0):

```
G = 0
U=0
Chosen_word = str(input("Choose a word of max 60 character(only uppercase)"))

n = Chosen_word.count("A")
U = n * 2
G = n 

print (U)
print (G)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Choose a word of max 60 character(only uppercase)SADDSAAAA
10
5
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.